# How to merge objects if variable exist and it is an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am experimenting with how to merge two variables and it is an object?

I have tried with this which seem to work:

```js
let data1 = {
  data1: "data1"
}

let data2 = {
  data2: "data2"
}

const items = {
  ...(data1 && typeof data1 === 'object' && { ...data1 }),
  ...(data2 && typeof data2 === 'object' && { ...data2 }),
}

console.log(items);
```

This is good or unless I am overcomplicating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...if variable exist...

If you mean that literally, the variable may not be declared, then you need to move the `typeof` check to the front in order to avoid trying to read the value of an undeclared variable. You can also take advantage of the fact that spreading `undefined`, `null`, or a boolean (like `false`) doesn't do anything (including not causing an error).

Here I've added a `data3` that doesn't exist to show that part in action:

```js
let data1 = {
    data1: "data1",
};

let data2 = {
    data2: "data2",
};

const items = {
    ...typeof data1 === "object" && data1,
    ...typeof data2 === "object" && data2,
    ...typeof data3 === "object" && data3,
};

console.log(items);
```

How that works (using `data1` as the example):

1. `typeof data1 === "object"` tells us two things:

   - That there's an in-scope identifier called `data1` (which means we can read its value without worrying about getting a `ReferenceError` for an undeclared variable)
   - That `data1`'s value is of type `"object"`
2. That combined with `&& data1` means we'll be using one of these values with spread:

   - `false` if `typeof data1 === "object"` is `false`, or
   - The value of `data1`, which is either an object or `null`

Spreading `null` doesn't do anything, and spreading `false` doesn't do anything, so we either get no properties from that spread operation or we get the own, enumerable properties of an object that `data1` references.

Comment: Thanks. Will this be a deep copy merge or should I use lodash merge?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back - Spread is shallow. If you want a deep copy, see [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) and adapt them (or, as you say, use `_.merge` if its trade-offs make sense for what you're doing).